# Div overlapping with outer divs on css transorm

Tags: html, css, z-index

```css
.demo-div{
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
 border: 1px solid #d6f5f5;
 background: #f6f6f6;
 padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
 min-height: 500px;
}

.demo-div .demo-div-content{
 padding: 0px !important;
}
.demo-div-inner{
 background: white;
 min-height: 70px;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 30px;
  transform:translateX(30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-div ">
    <div class="demo-div-content">
          <div class="demo-div-inner">swipe me out</div>                          </div>
</div>
```

When i apply translate to inner div , it comes on top of parent div.

But i want is that it should stay within parent on applying tranform.

Also i have event listener on demo-div-inner , so setting it z-index of parent div i.e. demo-div as -1 , stopped event listener from firing.

Answer (score 0):

Add Another attributes margin-right at your demo-div-inner class.

```css
.demo-div{
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
 border: 1px solid #d6f5f5;
 background: #f6f6f6;
 padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
 min-height: 500px;
   
}

.demo-div .demo-div-content{
 padding: 0px !important;
}

.demo-div-inner{
 background: white;
 min-height: 70px;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 30px;
    margin-right: 66px;
    transform:translateX(30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-div">
  <div class="demo-div-content">
          <div class="demo-div-inner">swipe me out</div>                          
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that will just reduce the width of div inner content.
It will not solve my problem

Comment: if you use transform:translateX(30%); it will move content 30% from its actual position ,so basically without reducing width , you can not achieve your desire scenario.

Comment: Isn't there any way using z index property.